# Circular motion question about Ferris wheel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

I have a small question that I couldn't be 100% sure about it. I'm gonna try to translate it from my native language and since I'm learning physics in my native language, some words may be off.

---

There is a Ferris wheel with a radius of 9 meters that do 4 cycles per minute.

a) What is the centripetal acceleration of a person inside the wheel?

b) What is the force applied to the 40-kilogram rider (by the chair he is sitting) when he is at the bottom and at the top?

c) What is the force applied to the 40-kilogram rider when he's at half of the bottom and top positions of the wheel, and what is the direction of the force?

Here are my answers. Feel free to correct them as I'm not too sure about them.

a) T=15 seconds

v=2*pi*9/15

ar=(v^2)/r=0.41

b) Fc = Centripetal force = (mv^2)/r

force at the bottom is Fc+mg, force at the top is Fc-mg

c) Don't have an idea.

Comment: Hi Eren and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: @JohnRennie thanks for the heads up! Thought homework-and-exercises tag at here would be an acceptable place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your a) looks but it looks like you've got your b) backwards! Since the centripetal force is always pulling towards the centre of the ferris wheel, at the top, both gravity and centripetal force are pulling downwards and thus F(top) = Fc+mg  and at the bottom, gravity is pulling downwards (as always) and the centripetal force is pulling towards the middle, thus upwards in this case so F(bottom) = Fc - Fg.

c) If i understand your question correctly, it seems to be asking when the rider is halfway between the top and the bottom (ie: at 90 degrees from the top of the wheel) what is the applied force.  Thus, if the rider is on the right side of the wheel, we have the centripetal force pulling inwards to the left, and gravity pulling directly downwards.  Not considering the other forces, we can say that F(x) = -Fc , if we consider leftwards the negative x direction, while F(y) = mg.  then you have a vector in two dimensions 
(-Fc,mg) for which you can calculate the total magnitude sqrt(Fc^2 + (mg)^2) and direction tan(theta) = mg/Fc if we consider theta the downward angle from the horizontal. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know why it got downvoted but it helped.